# jquery: displaying image in top right corner

Tags: jquery, image

i am pretty new to jquery and hope this is the right place to ask.

my problem is the following.
when i mouseover a certain element on a page, i want that a certain image is displayed in the top right corner of the page, no matter where the it is currently scrolled.

how can i achieve that?
thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(function(){
  $("#certain_element").mouseover(function(){
    $("#certain_img").css({position:"fixed",right:"0px",top:"0px"});
  });
});
```

see working example on http://jsbin.com/orace/

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the `position: fixed` CSS property with `top: 0; right: 0`.

If you need IE 6 support, check [this page](http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2009/09/css-position-fixed-solution.html).

```
$("#triggerId").mouseover(function (e) {
    $("#cornerImageId").show();
});
```

And have in your CSS:

```
#cornerImageId {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```